# Rounding necessary exception after setting scale and rounding for BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to summarize my net and gross prices coming from the database.
In the MySQL database these numbers are stored like this:

```
decimal(38,3)
```

I already read through the related Stackoverflow questions, but I still can't figure it out, why I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary
    at java.math.BigDecimal.commonNeedIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4148)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.needIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4204)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRound(BigDecimal.java:4112)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(BigDecimal.java:2452)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.longValueExact(BigDecimal.java:3090)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.intValueExact(BigDecimal.java:3147)
```

For this code:

```
setSumNetPrice(0);
setSumGrossPrice(0);

for(MyReport report : result){
    if(null != report.getNetPrice()){

        BigDecimal netPrice = report.getNetPrice().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        setSumNetPrice(getSumNetPrice() + netPrice.intValueExact());
    }

    if(null != report.getGrossMoney()){

        BigDecimal grossMoney = report.getGrossMoney().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        setSumGrossPrice(getSumGrossPrice() + report.getGrossMoney().intValueExact());
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

EDIT:

I edited my code, but I'm still getting the same Exception from the "grossMoney.intValueExact()" line...

```
for(MyReport report : result){
    if(null != report.getNetPrice()){

        BigDecimal netPrice = report.getNetPrice().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        setSumNetPrice(getSumNetPrice() + netPrice.intValueExact());
    }

    if(null != report.getGrossMoney()){

        BigDecimal grossMoney = report.getGrossMoney().setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        setSumGrossPrice(getSumGrossPrice() + grossMoney.intValueExact());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to round the BigDecimal before calling `intValueExact()`

Comment: But I had... The rounding is before the intValueExact(), or am I wrong?

Comment: But you don't even use the value that you scale (`grossMoney` not used after).

Comment: Also you should use [round](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round-java.math.MathContext-) I think.

Comment: edited, but still the same Exception :(

Comment: Try to replace `setScale` with `round()`

Comment: Same with: BigDecimal grossMoney = report.getGrossMoney().round(java.math.MathContext.DECIMAL32); BUT only on the grossMoney line...Why is the netPrice okay?! I don't get it...

Comment: I guess you get the error because you round to a non-integer value. Use SetScale(0, ...);

Comment: What do you even want to acomplish? decimal(38,3) is a decimal, `intValueExact()` will return an int, which isn't possible without rounding (or truncating) it.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the comma to the right. Thus:

```
long value = new BigDecimal(4.13).movePointRight(2).longValueExact();
```

The value after conversion will be **413**